# Scala: How to Unit Test a function I have which makes an API call using mock/stub?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking

I have a function which makes an API call to a an external API

Let us say the function does something simple like the below. FYI need to import `scala.io.Source`

```
  def myFunction(apiRequestUrl: String) : MyObject = {
    val response: String = Source.fromURL(apiRequestUrl).mkString
    val formatedResponse: MyObject = formatResponseFunction(response)
    formatedResponse
  }
```

I know that some error codes I could receive are 400, 404, etc... and I'd like to just handle any error code generically from this. How could this be done? The examples I've found seem to be testing a person's own built REST API, and not function calls to someone else's external API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to inject the dependencies you want to replace with mocks, static calls within a function can't be mocked/stubbed.

In your Scenario you have another problem: your dependency `Source` is an object, and you can't mock objects, only non-final classes and traits. Furthermore, it is considered a bad practice to mock 3rd party APIs.

A good way to solve all those problems would be to re-write the code like

```
trait HttpAdapter {
  def fromUrl(apiRequestUrl: String): String = Source.fromURL(apiRequestUrl).mkString
}

object HttpAdapter extends HttpAdapter

def myFunction(apiRequestUrl: String, httpAdapter: HttpAdapter = HttpAdapter) : MyObject = {
  val response: String = httpAdapter.fromUrl(apiRequestUrl)
  val formatedResponse: MyObject = formatResponseFunction(response)
  formatedResponse
}

"myFunction" should "work" in {
  //create mock
  val http = mock[HttpAdapter]
  
  //stub mock
  http.fromUrl("some url") shouldReturn "result"
  
  //inject mock
  myFunction("some url", http) shouldBe MyObject
}
```

Notice I've wrapped the third party API in a class I have full control over (`HttpAdapter`) and then I mock that one

Then I inject `httpAdapter` as a parameter, but I provide a default value so the callers do not need to worry about it, while I can still override it with a mock or stub in test code.

Also note that I've used mockito-scala instead of regular mockito, so the stubbing syntax is different.

Comment: Thank you for a great response. I'm still new so thanks for sharing some best practices as well. Would that trait example be known as an adapter pattern? I noticed that you wrote "object HttpAdapter extends " but did not say what it extends. Could you complete that?

Comment: Glad it helped! - oh yes, copy paste error, I fixed the extends now - if it solves your problem mark it as the correct answer so it can benefit more people!

Comment: Yeah, this is awesome. Thank you.

Comment: After trying this out with regular Mockito framework I get an error stating "String cannot be returned by get$default$2()
get$default$2() should return int".

Comment: Regular mockito does not play well with some scala features, that error seems to be related to a default argument returning a value class (just a wild guess here)... could you try with mockito-scala? if it doesn't work there, please create an issue in github and provide enough code so it can be easily copy and pasted to reproduce the error

Comment: I actually got it to work (using regular Mockito framework). I wasn't passing in "http" object into my function call, and letting it use the default one supplied in the constructor which wasn't mocked. Thanks for the help!

Comment: After reading through Adapter pattern online, I wouldn't really call this an adapter pattern. From GOF  --> “Convert the interface of a class into another interface clients expect. Adapter lets classes work together that could not otherwise because of incompatible interfaces.” [9, p. 139]. It's really just more of an interface correct? Could we rename it to HttpInterface?

Comment: Well, arguably, an Adapter is a class that hides an interface/API you don't wan't/can't use and provide one that suits your needs, which is what we're doing here in a way, also the example is way too simple to assume any pattern or desing structure. At the same time, it's just a name, so you're free to call it whatever you like/suits better with your overall app

Answer (score 2):

For mocking the external service calls, you could use Mockito which is a mocking framework. Mockito is very simple to use and you can provide stubs for your external calls. For example

```
val m = mock[io.Source.type]
```

Here you mock the Source and then you provide your desired behaviour on invocation of the `fromUrl` function.
i.e

```
when(m.fromUrl("external service url")) thenReturn("result")
```